# ArrayBuffer's Binary clarification

Tags: javascript, binary, arraybuffer

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView/setInt8

Just want to clarify something here, when this article says:

> The setInt8() method stores a signed 8-bit integer (byte) value at the specified byte offset from the start of the DataView.<<

and then you execute this code

```
var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(8);
var dataview = new DataView(buffer);
dataview.setInt8(1, 3);
dataview.setInt8(3, -3);
```

buffer is actually:

```
[
00000000,
00000011,
00000000,
10000011,
00000000,
00000000,
00000000,
00000000
]
```

with the highest number possible being `127`?

I think I've confirmed that with

```
dataview.setInt8(1,128);
dataview.getInt8(1); // -127
```

However... I'm then confused as to why it reverts back...

```
dataview.setInt8(1, 255);
dataview.getInt8(1); // -1

dataview.setInt8(1, 257);
dataview.getInt8(1); // 1
```

Shouldn't I be getting an error with `dataview.setInt8(1,257)` since `256` is beyond the scope of the 8-bit integer?  I'm just trying to confirm that buffer is actually the array of binary I listed above... so this would make a difference if that 8-bit integer was converted to a 16 bit integer... thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try this:

```
dataview.setInt8(1,1);
dataview.getInt16(1); // 256
dataview.setInt8(1,257);
dataview.getInt16(1); // 256
```

you can confirm that setInt8 is only writing to one byte of the buffer, even when given an input value that's more than 8 bits. So you're safe there.

What's odd is that `.setInt8()` and `.setUint8()` appear to be the same function (on Chrome, the only browser I tried). Neither `.setInt8(1,255)` nor `.setUint8(1,-1)` return an error, and `.setInt8(1,-1)` and `.setUint8(1,-1)` have identical effects.

Additionally, you asked 'with the highest number possible being 127?'. Yes, IF you're reading the buffer with `getInt8()`. Reading it with `getUint8()` or `getInt16()` or etc could return a value higher than 127. Unlike the set functions, the get functions appear to (correctly) behave differently with regards to signing.

Starting with an empty buffer, if you execute:

```
dataview.setInt8(1,3);
dataview.setInt8(3,3);
```

the buffer will contain:

```
00000000 00000011 00000000 11111101
```

You can verify this by trying:

```
dataview.getInt32(0); // 196861 = 110000000011111101
```

Negative numbers are being represented via [Two's Complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations) in the buffer

Comment: I suppose for my purposes, I can just restrict myself to the first 255 values, but what you're saying is that I was correct, this is the binary from the first code snippet?  [ 00000000, 00000011, 00000000, 10000011, 00000000, 00000000, 00000000, 00000000 ]

Comment: Whoops! No, actually. I hadn't read your array closely enough. Updating answer.

Comment: Interesting, is there an options object somewhere that I can use to have these int's unsigned?  I don't really need negative numbers

Comment: Instead of using `getInt8()` to retrieve the values, use `getUint8()`. The internal representation is the same either way; what changes is the way it's being read.

Comment: Actually, so, if it's two's compliment, 10000011 is actually -127... as in dataview.setInt8(1,131); will give me that binary value?  That works for me